# How to change the value of a button that is in the same class of other buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a group of buttons that are assigned to a class and I want to change the value of a specific button from that class.

```
{% for titles in title %}
  <table>
    <tr> 
      <td> <input type = "button" class = "openGraph" value = "{{titles.title}}" id="{% url 'openGraph' title=titles.id %}"> </td> 
      <td> <input type = "button" class = "deleteGraph" value = "Delete" id="{% url 'deleteGraph' title=titles.id %}"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
{% endfor %}
```

For those unfamiliar with Django, the `{{}}` represents the context passed from the server and are just values from the database.

This is the javascript code I attempted:

```
    currentTitle = $('#currentTitle').val()
    title = $('#newTitle').val()
    $('.openGraph').each(function(i, obj) {
      if ($(this).val() == currentTitle) {
        $(this).val(title);
      }
    })
```

There are a group of buttons shown with the default value of "Untitled Graph". The user can edit a button by clicking an input text which is set on a page and renaming the value of the input text edits the value of the button. The input text that the user clicks on is called currentTitle and the other input text that the user has to edit the title is called newTitle and can be seen below:

```
    <input id = "currentTitle" type="text" name="currentTitle" value="{{currentTitle}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveTitleModal">
    <input id = "newTitle" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="newTitle">
```

The issue with my code is that if I rename a button it renames all the buttons. I want to rename the button I specifically said so via the input text.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You've giden a very rough outline of what you're trying to do, but no detail of the output you want, or description of why your current code doesn't work.

Comment: in addition to @RoryMcCrossan's comment (which I agree with), your JS code relates to elements with class `currentGraph` yet the HTML you have shown includes no such elements (no matter what data is retrieved from the database).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the question, please let me know if you have any further questions so I can clarify the question further.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have updated the code, any questions, please let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still more than a little unsure as to what exactly you want to happen. And your Javascript snippet is lacking context - what are `currentTitle` and `title`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I updated again and here are two gifs to illustrate my program 
[link](https://gph.is/2RVv8ET) and [link2](https://gph.is/2Rri0Cf)

Comment: Thanks. that's given me a (slightly) better understanding. I think this problem is inevitable due to the way you've coded it - you're changing the value of all buttons whose value matches that of the `currentTitle` input. If these were likely to be unique then it would be OK, but you've assigned them all the same default value, so changing one will inevitably change them all. It seems to me that you need to have a way for the user to specify which button they want to change, other than by title. One way would be to have a separate input box for each button.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for the reply, each title that has the input text also has a hidden input text which has a unique id, if that makes it easier. 

`<input type = "hidden" id = "idOfGraph" name = "graphId" class="currentGraph">`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have two buttons with the same class and you want to change just one of this button 
try this:

```
'<td> <input type = "button" class = "openGraph editmy" value = "{{titles.title}}" id="{% url 'openGraph' title=titles.id %}"> </td> <td> <input type = "button" class = "deleteGraph" value = "Delete" id="{% url 'deleteGraph' title=titles.id %}"> </td> </tr>'
```

and tag you class element ("editmy")

Comment: Please read the conversation to clarify my issue further, sorry if my question wasn't clear.